# How can it be determined that a cast or type test is unchecked?

Tags: types, implementation, java

In languages like Java that use type erasure for generics, some casts are considered unchecked. One example is casting a value of `Object` to `List<String>`. On the other hand, casting from `Iterable<String>` to `List<String>` is allowed because the type parameter matches. Casting `Object` to `List<?>` is also allowed due to the wildcard.

In [JLS 5.1.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6.2), it states

> A narrowing reference conversion from a type S to a parameterized class or interface type T is unchecked, unless at least one of the following is true:
>
> - All of the type arguments of T are unbounded wildcards.
> - T <: S, and S has no subtype X other than T where the type arguments of X are not contained in the type arguments of T.

- What is required to check the second criteria listed above?
- Is there a well known algorithm for performing this check?
- What edge cases need to be considered?

Answer (score 2):

The second criterion essentially checks the subtyping rule of your language. In Java, it's inheritance plus covariance. For instance:

- If type `A` extends/implements type `B`, then `A :< B` (same when adding generic parameters)
- If `A :< B` then `A[] :< B[]` (this rule is true in Java, but is flawed)

So, an algorithm for checking this would be a graph-theoretic algorithm that detects if a node is an ancestor of another node.

Regarding edge cases, you may have to deal with special subtyping rules, for example, `int` is a subtype of `long` (check the Liskov substitution principle!), but there is no inheritance between them.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. I think it is clear why an unchecked cast is a problem. I'm more interested in how the compiler detects that the cast is unchecked.

Comment: @MI3Guy hi, I rewrote my answer.